# Emulating FS create file behavior in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I got a files table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE files (
    id   SERIAL  PRIMARY KEY,
    path VARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

And I wanna write an sql transaction to emulate FS behavior when you tryna create a file:

- if a file with such path doesn't exist yet -> create it
- if it does -> create a file with name like `{filename} (1)`
- if such file already exists too -> find the greatest available number `n` and paste it into `{filename} ({n})`

So I'm stuck in that moment:

```sql
WITH f AS (
  SELECT path
  FROM files
  WHERE path ~ '^(kek|kek \(\d+\))$'
  ORDER BY path DESC
)
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(f) > 1 THEN (
          WITH cte AS (
            SELECT *
            FROM (
              SELECT SUBSTRING(f.path, 6, LENGTH(f.path) - 6)::numeric AS i
              FROM f
              WHERE f.path != 'kek'
            ) AS n
            WHERE i > 0
            ORDER BY i
          )
          -- SELECT LAG(arr, 1, NULL) OVER (
          --     PARTITION BY arr
          --     ORDER BY arr
          --     ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
          --   )
          -- FROM a
          SELECT ARRAY(
            SELECT i + 1
            FROM cte
          )
        )
        WHEN COUNT(f) = 0 THEN 'kek (0)'
        ELSE 'kek'
    END
FROM f
```

that gives me a sorted array (or a query) of such numbers. But how to find the next greatest available number?

Maybe you got something better in your mind cause this query already looks too enormous for such task IMO

## [DB Fiddle to play with it](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i6XCvTSi5cpAVu5AAfiNqm/8)

Comment: with the data provided, what would be the next number, and why i+1

Comment: Using a sequence can be much more performant.

Comment: You need to provide an output you require from the input provided!

Answer (score -1):

Do you provide a filename to generate a new file number for the specific file?

I have tried to solve it but if you could let us what input will be provided to the query and what output you expect?

This query will generate the latest file number + 1 for the patterns provided in the where clause in the CTE;

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS files;

CREATE TABLE files (
    id   SERIAL  PRIMARY KEY,
    path VARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO files (path) VALUES
    ('lol'),
    ('kek and bek (333)'),
    ('kek (1)'),
    ('kek (2)'),
    ('kek (9)'),
    ('kek (10)'),
    ('kek (1)(3)'),
    ('kek (1)(3)(400)'),
    ('kek (1)(2)(401)'),
    ('cheburek');

WITH CTE AS (
SELECT
    path, 
    CASE 
        WHEN POSITION('(' IN path) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(path FROM 1 FOR POSITION('(' IN path) - 1)
            ELSE path
        END AS fileName -- before_opening_parenthesis
        , STRING_TO_ARRAY(replace(replace(replace(path, ')(', '-'), '(', ''), ')',''), ' ')  AS words_array
        , STRING_TO_ARRAY(replace(replace(replace(path, ')(', ' '), '(', ''), ')',''), ' ')  AS words_array2
        , NULLIF(regexp_replace(path::text, '\D','','g'), '')::numeric as num
FROM 
  files
  WHERE 
    path ~ '^(lol)$' or 
    path ~ '^(kek and bek \(\d+\))$' or 
    path ~ '^(cheburek)$' or 
    path ~ '^(kek|kek \(\d+\))$'
) 
SELECT filename, max(Coalesce(num,0))+1 Filenumber FROM CTE
GROUP by filename
```

Output

```
 - filename      Filenumber
----------------------------
cheburek                  1
kek                      11
kek and bek             334
lol                       1
```

Comment: Actually it has nothing with what I described

Answer (score -2):

My commented attempts with using the `LAG` window function were in a right way. So the final answer is:

```sql
INSERT INTO files (path)
WITH f AS (
  SELECT path
  FROM files
  WHERE path ~ ('^(' || 'kek' || '|' || 'kek' || ' \(\d+\))$')
  ORDER BY path DESC
)
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN NOT EXISTS(SELECT f.path FROM f WHERE f.path = 'kek') THEN 'kek'
        ELSE
            CASE
                WHEN COUNT(f) > 1 THEN (
                    WITH cte AS (
                      SELECT *
                      FROM (
                        SELECT SUBSTRING(f.path, 6, LENGTH(f.path) - 6)::numeric AS i
                        FROM f
                        WHERE f.path != 'kek'
                      ) AS n
                      WHERE i > 0
                      ORDER BY i
                    )
                    SELECT 'kek' || '(' || COALESCE(t.next_i, (SELECT cte.i + 1 FROM cte ORDER BY cte.i DESC LIMIT 1)) || ')'
                    FROM cte
                    FULL OUTER JOIN (
                      SELECT prev_i + 1 AS next_i
                      FROM (
                        SELECT LAG(i, 1, 0) OVER() AS prev_i, i
                        FROM cte
                      ) t
                      WHERE prev_i != t.i - 1
                      LIMIT 1
                    ) t ON cte.i = t.next_i
                    LIMIT 1
                )
                WHEN COUNT(f) = 0 THEN 'kek' || ' (1)'
                ELSE 'kek'
        END
    END
FROM f;
```

I separated `kek` as it's going to be an argument, not just a part of a plain query. The magic number `6` is also a pasted value since it's a length of the `kek (` part, and I'm going to calculate it in my program and paste it to the plain query.

It's also available as a [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i6XCvTSi5cpAVu5AAfiNqm/14)